# Is there a formula in Excel to allow a search in one column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

We have an email database with the home address for each person in it and we need to know if we can enter a formula to search the database to find the specific cities. The column for cities is in the "G" column.

Comment: I think you're looking for the [vlookup](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php) command.

Comment: Please don't call a table or spreadsheet a database. The day our functional lead starts calling herself a DBA, I quit!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Superuser. Knowing what version you are using helps you get a more specific answer.

The easiest solution would be to just filter your data by city. In earlier versions this is done by making a list and sorting by the column you want. In newer versions you can make a table with the data and sort it using the filter buttons in the column headings.

Here are detailed [instructions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-an-excel-list-HP001031716.aspx) how to make a list in Excel 2003.

Here are [instructions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-create-an-excel-table-HA010359200.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA101829993) how to make a table in Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Just highlight that column (by clicking at the top) or select the data cells you want and hit Ctrl-F. Then your search is limited to just the selected data.